# How to load Shell before loading desktop environment?

Tags: boot, command-line, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-minimal

I have installed Ubuntu 20.4 minimal from its mini.iso image, after that I didn't choose a desktop environment, so I directly go to shell after booting. In my shell I installed budgie desktop environment, but I forgot to install gnome-terminal, and I rebooted.

So I have a Ubuntu 20.4 minimal without any terminal, is there any way to load shell instead of desktop environment, so I could install gnome-terminal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can get to a root shell prompt from GRUB:**

- Reboot your computer and from GRUB select "Advanced Options for Ubuntu"

*If GRUB does not come up on your system automatically, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after turning on your device to bring it up (for UEFI systems)*

- Select a kernel option with "recovery mode".
- Toggle "Enable networking", otherwise the file system will be mounted read-only.
- Select "Drop to root shell prompt"
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now you have a root shell prompt and you can install software using `apt` commands.  Use the command `reboot` when you are finished.

---

**Another option is to use a `tty`**.  You should be able to access a terminal from your desktop environment by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

You can get back to your desktop with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! I tried second option bit for me it works with Ctrl + Alt + F3! Appreciate your help, good luck.